# Investigating Garbage collection cycle causes

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

In a current BPM based application (deployed in JBOSS AS 4.2.3) running in production, there are some performance issues noticed which is because of some longer running GC suspension cycles during peak load. Analyzing more into the same, I found the following output to the jstat utility for the running JVM instance.

/usr/jdk1.6.0-x64/bin/jstat -gccapacity 5583
 NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC      PGCMN    PGCMX     PGC       PC     YGC    FGC
838848.0 1677696.0 1677696.0 167744.0 167744.0 1342208.0  3355456.0  6710912.0  6710912.0  6710912.0  21248.0 524288.0 480084.0 480084.0   8448   268

/usr/jdk1.6.0-x64/bin/jstat -gcutil 5583 1s
  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  0.00  46.33  23.11  81.23  60.38   8451 1386.335   268  159.553 1545.887
  0.00  46.33  27.99  81.23  60.38   8451 1386.335   268  159.553 1545.887

In the first command, (with option -gccapacity) I observed that, the NGC = NGCMX and OGC = OGCMX. That means, the current Old gen capacity reaches to the max old gen capacity and current new gen capacity reaches the max new gen capacity.

I would like to understand, can this be possibly a cause of frequent GC cycles with some big  executions (taking more than 25-30 sec sometimes) ?

For the current resolution, we have increased the Max JVM heap memory from 8 GB to 9GB. However, we need to understand the possible reasons so that, we can raise the same to the Developers team to optimize the applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand the cause of memory usage I suggest you use a memory profiler.  One option is to use VisualVM, however a commercial profiler like YourKit may handle larger memory sizes better.

Increasing from 8 to 9 GB isn't likely to make much difference.  If you have the memory try 16 GB or 30 GB and see if this more than you need and then reduce it.

If you can't profile your application in production and test doesn't reproduce the same behaviour you can take use `jmap -histo` to get an idea of the biggest consumers of memory.  Sometimes this gives you a clue.

Comment: +1 JVisualVM is nice. And there's a feature for remote profiling. Using a profiler you may be able to find leaks inside the application.

Comment: A profiler can help you find out why you are retaining more memory than you think you should under load.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the answer. I will try jmap -histo to dig more into the reason, and also see if any tools I can use as suggested by you. However I would like to understand if NGC = NGCMX and OGC = OGCMX (as in my current case), is it a matter of concern and increasing memory, can be likely bring down NGC and OGC less than NGCMX and OGCMX values respectively ? Note : I have got these values with execution of jstat -gccapacity <PID>.

Comment: Unless you have a memory leak, increasing the maximum enough will result in the maximum being high than what is used.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is about the **GC**, maybe you could try to use another **GC algorithm**, or even a combination of then.
The **scenario** you described really seems like GC algorithm not sultable for your needs.

The algorithm **Parallel Collector** (you can enable this using **-XX:+UseParallelGC**) can run minor collects in parallel.
Warning: This algorithm is "stop-the-world" one, but can make use of multiple processors to execute the GC.

There's also the **-XX:+UseParallelOldGC**, that enable a collector for the old GEN.

These algorthms change from a VM to another. So see which version of the JVM you're using and try to choose right algorithm for your needs.

*As Peter said in his answer, a profiler will help you evaluate your application, the chosen GC algorithm and make your decision.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, will see if this could be any solution to the existing issue.